# onMouseMove override keeps onMouseUp from working

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have a `TreeViewItem` which its `onMouseUp` is not fired, I tried shrinking my complicated class and I was able to produce a working example of a `onMouseUp` not working, it seems the `onMouseMove` override is causing this behavior which is a mystery because I am using `onMouseUp` and I'm not overriding the `onMouseMove`!
How can I fix this code?

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Layouts,
  FMX.TreeView;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure MouseMove(Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single); override;
    procedure onItemMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  treeView: TTreeView;
  treeViewItem: TTreeViewItem;
begin
  treeView := TTreeView.Create(nil);
  treeView.Position.X := 0;
  treeView.Position.Y := 0;
  treeView.Width := 200;
  treeView.Height := 300;
  treeView.Parent := form2;

  treeViewItem := TTreeViewItem.Create(nil);
  treeViewItem.Parent := treeView;
  treeViewItem.Text := 'This is a test';
  treeViewItem.OnMouseUp := onItemMouseUp;
end;

procedure TForm2.onItemMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X: Single; Y: Single);
begin
  ShowMessage('onItemMouseUp');
end;

procedure TForm2.MouseMove(Shift: TShiftState; X: Single; Y: Single);
begin

end;

end.
```

Comment: Another way is by setting it to null, I suppose.  Instead of posing this hypothetical, maybe you could show us the actual problem you're having, with some code that reproduces it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have a class inherited from `TTreeView`, somehow the items i create lose their assigned procedure ! and become empty ( i checked this by assigning the procedure again in run time), i want to find the problem but i don't understand the ways my `onMouseUp` procedure could have gotten deleted or replaced !

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thats the problem, the main code is too complicated and i was not able to produce this problem in a test case, i simply do not understand what could cause my `Ttreeviewitems` to behave like this, obviously i have only one assignment call in the entire unit, which is why i'm looking for the possible ways it could have been effected.

Comment: I would start looking for scope problems.  Places where these events could go out of scope.

Comment: To produce a test case start with your complicated code. Then remove a bit at a time until your problem disappears or is small enough to post here. When the problem disappears (if it does) the code you just deleted is probably where your problem is.

Comment: Is it possible to set a break point on `onMouseUp` to see where it changes ? i can only see a `property OnMouseUp;` , where does the assignment for onMouseUp happens?

Comment: @Dsm, In the end i ended up delete each procedure and testing the app as you mentioned and after a lot of work i found the problem, thanks.

Comment: I edited the question and made a verifiable version of my issue, even though my problem is already solved, i rewrote the question to keep it out of "on hold", i hope this question can help other people with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

`MouseMove(...) override;`  overrides every other `onMouseMove`, this is usually used if you need to ensure execution on `MouseMove` no matter what kind of object you are focusing, since you are overriding `MoveMove` you have to use the keyword `Inherited` inside the body which will ensure all the other `onMouseMove`s that are inherited work as well.
So you simply need to change your MouseMove to this:

```
procedure TForm2.MouseMove(Shift: TShiftState; X: Single; Y: Single);
begin
  Inherited;
end;
```

Comment: Generally when you override a procedure like this you should always call inherited *unless* you specifically want to stop the ancestor doing whatever it does. Calling inherited should be your default position.

Comment: @Dsm yes,that is correct, but why is it that `MoveMove` stops `onMouseUp`?

Comment: I can't say for sure without checking, but I have observed that mouse actions are not necessarily where you would expect them. Firemonkey is cross platform, so the only platform independant way of checking whether a mouse up event has occurred that I can think of is by comparing its current state with its previous state. The state is available in ShiftState, so maybe the ancestor MoveMove procedure generates the OnMouseMove event based on this information. I don't know, though. You could check.